# Android phone hanging because of continuous location update

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, locationmanager, android-gps, android-developer-api

I am developing an android application. In my application, I need continuous location update and I need to store that lat lng's into firestore documents. All working is fine. I am getting location updations continuously and storing in firestore. But the problem is my android phone hangs with-in 5 minutes when I opened my app. Below is my code regarding the location updations.

```
LocationManager locmngr; // Location manager declaration

locationUpdate(); // Initializing the method in onCreate()

public void locationUpdate()
    {
        locmngr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 12);
            return;
        }

        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = locmngr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = locmngr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("GPS network not enabled");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    //get gps
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }

        try {
            locmngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 7, 30, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

                    // Add a marker at your current location and move the camera
                    //Log.e("location", location.toString());

                    if(!user_id.isEmpty()){

                        // code to write lat longs into firestore
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TabsActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 12);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            try {

                locationUpdate();
                TabsActivity.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 1000);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };
```

I need location update for every second. What I have to do for this(Phone hanging). Please suggest me any other possibilities. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the phone hanging? Is your app getting slow, or all apps, or does the phone stop reacting to all input, or something else? Have you used tools to check which apps are consuming memory or CPU?

Comment: Its better to use `FusedLocationProviderAPI`.

Comment: you need to write a separate service for fetching user location. and make sure it should run on separate thread instead of UI thread.

Comment: The phone stop reacting to all input and after some time the phone is restarting by itself. #Roland Weber

Comment: you should use google api client to get location updates efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Your `m_Runnable` is posting itself to run every second. Every time it runs, it calls `locationUpdate()` which registers a new `LocationListener`. After five minutes, you would have 300 listeners processing each update. That's probably why your app is getting bogged down!

You do not need to register a new listener every time you want to receive a location update. Just register it once in an activity setup lifecycle method. Don't forget to unregister it in the corresponding teardown lifecycle method. You should probably use `onStart`/`onStop`, not `onCreate`/`onDestroy`. If you need to receive updates when the app is in the background, the listener should belong to a `Service`.